# How is the cliched plot device of 'not realising a Dr. is female' interpreted in German, where it would be obvious?

Tags: english-to-german

In English the title "Doctor" is the same whether or not the person is male/female, but in German there are two different words for this.

Answer (score 8):

Not sure about that plot device, but it should work the same in German. Yes, there is *Doktor* and *Doktorin* in principle, but *Doktorin* is rarely used.

In practice, when addressing either male or female doctor by name and with title, you would in both cases say, for example, *Doktor Müller*. If you address a Doctor only by title, then you would say *Herr Doktor* for men and *Frau Doktor* for women.

If you talk about a doctor in his/her absence, then you have the choice between all three forms: *Doktor Müller*, or *der Doktor/die Doktorin* or "Herr/Frau Doktor".

Also, now the word Doktor, having it written so often in so few sentences, has lost all meaning and just sounds really weird...

Comment: +1: I'd say "Doktor Müller" would allow the most natural translation of the plot device.

Comment: Very often, when a doctor is female both gender and title are used *"Frau Doktor Müller"* as opposed to just *"Doktor Müller"* in case he is male. To overcome this obvious discrimination some  always use *"Herr Doktor Müller"* as well, but this still is far from general practise. "*Doktorin*" is not used very often.

Comment: Is 'Doktor' a title or is it a 'Grad'? Afaik, it is a 'Grad', not a 'Title'.

Comment: @Hackworth: A bit off topic: "has lost all meaning" This is called *semantic satiation* (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_satiation).

Comment: @user unknown: In ordinary conversation "Titel" is used for "Grad".

Comment: @Takkat: Maybe that is a peculiarity from South-Western German, but I'd consider *Doktor Müller* to be a *very* informal way of speaking. In my experience (in any at least semi-respectful context), *Herr Doktor Müller* and *Frau Doktor Müller* are the only ways to both directly address and speak about a doctor whose name is Müller. It should, however, be noted, that the English way of using the title (i.e. no *Herr* or *Frau* in front) is generally used in dubbed American movies/tv series (along with untranslated titles), so *Captain Kirk* remains *Captain Kirk*, not *Herr Kapitän Kirk*.